# Can Kale control her full power when she isnt in berserker mode?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

Kale in berserker mode was able to take a kamehameha wave from Goku undamaged or almost undamaged. Now most fans didnt like the idea of Kale being as strong as a super saiyan blue and started to argue Kale wasnt as strong or stronger than a super saiyan blue because Goku said "I'm going to use a little more power", what they say it means Goku wasnt using his full power in super saiyan blue. I dont buy this idea for 3 reasons:

- If Goku really said "I'm going to use a little more power" (some subtitles translates it as "I'm going to use more power" without the "little", if Goku really said so, he could be refering to him not using kaioken on top of blue. By using Super Saiyan Blue in full power, Goku is still using 5% or 10% of his power (he can use super saiyan blue kaioken x10 or x20 where he increases 10 times or 20 times his power from Blue)
- Vegeta mentioned Kale is "a monster". Why would he call a monster someone who isnt as strong or stronger than him.
- Jiren didnt bother to fight Goku or Vegeta super saiyan blue, but he bothered to take Kale as a challenge, this actually is a hint than Kale showed more power than Goku and Vegeta at the time, who already fought in Super Saiyan Blue. And by the way, Hit was also around and Jiren didnt bother to fight him, and we know Hit's power is around a Super Saiyan Blue.

Having said all that, later Kale in her controlled stated wasnt able to hurt Goku in super saiyan god, though she could handle an energy blast from Goku in super saiyan god (something Caulifla in SSJ2 couldnt do) . This to me shows Kale's power in her controlled stated is close to a super saiyan god, or at least stronger than a SSJ2, but not equal or stronger than super saiyan god.

Then my question is, are there reasons or arguments to believe Kale can use her full power when she isnt in berserker mode?

Comment: Latest episode, when Kale is berserk again and holding hands with Caulifla, and Caulifla's words bring her back to sanity, I believe someone from U7 makes mention of her "being able to control her power". I'll look it up when I get home. If that's the case, would it count as proof? Currently the sideline characters have been less than perfect in their estimations of people's strength.

Answer (score 1):

You made a lot of incorrect assumpitons

Firstly, You need to note that All of Goku's fights until his fight with Jiren was him just goofing off. He was not fighting anyone seriously. Also you are right about him holding back and he did hold back a significant amount when he hit Kale with the Kamehameha. If goku had gone all power, then he would've used Kaioken which he didn't.

Secondly, a monster doesn't imply the other person is stronger. You might perhaps me referring to this based on Freiza's reference to Jiren as a monster. It was just because of her rather vicious nature and aggressive behavior firing ki blasts all around had Vegeta refer to her as a monster. Not because she was stronger than him

Jiren didn't fight Kale as a challenge. He did it to just stop the rampage she was on and you see her disturbing the entire tournament and she even knocked one of his teamate out. This is also seen when Universe 2 fire the hearts. Jiren was about to fire a beam attack at Ribrianne but Vegeta did it right before. Does this mean Jiren was interested in fighting Ribrianne? The only fighter Jiren has been interested to fight is Goku because we see him looking at him interested and approaches him for battle. Even hit attacked him and he responded.

Finally, Kale's controlled state is just as strong as she was in her Berserker state. Possibly even stronger because she gets to control her power this time. Also, Goku was fighting very seriously when she fought with Kale the second time around, which is why we see Kale trying a little harder. She wasn't injured after deflecting that Ki blast

Kale LSSJ mastered is just as strong as her using her berserker mode and it's very obvious she's stronger than SSJG and this is why. We see Jiren blocking punches from SSJG goku with a single finger and he had to try a little to block attacks from SSJB Goku. This indicates SSJB is significantly stronger than SSJG. Kefla in her base form was completely dominating SSJG Goku. SSJ2 is nothing compared to SSJ3 and SSJG is a much higher multiplier than SSJ3. Hence Caulifla's power isn't that high. Kale, on the other hand, must be exponentially stronger than SSJG Goku if base kefla is capable of fighting so easily with SSJG Goku. Also based on the title, SSJB Goku is not strong enough to beat Kefla. I think with that we can establish the fact that Kale LSSJ Is > SSJ Goku

Also, it has to be noted, that goku was just fooling around against Berserker Kale. Unlike his current fight with Kale and Caulifla where he has been very serious.